# Cannot Import the bak to GCP Cloud SQL due to compatibility level

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm getting this error when performing the Import BAK to the GCP SQL Cloud SQL SQL Server 2017 Standard.

`ERROR: (gcloud.sql.import.bak) [ERROR SQL SERVER EXTERNAL WARNING] 120 is not a supported compatibility level. Supported: [140, 130, 120, 110, 100]`

My exporting server running **120** , checked by this query:

```
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'mydb-name';
```

and this query:

```
SELECT @@version
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4) - 12.0.6329.1 (X64) Enterprise Edition

Here're my steps:

- Exporting the BAK file from my server (120)
- Create the SQL instance with SQL Server 2017 Standard, also created the user login (same as my exporting server)
- Perform the import command: `gcloud beta sql import bak my-sql-instance gs://my-bucket/file.bak --database=mydb-name`

I don't know why I get this In-compatible error because last month, It worked normally.

I have also tried with the Cloud SQL Enterprise but no luckily.
Anyone facing this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who want to ref:

- Import the *.bak to the server which is running SQL Server version >120
- Do the Upgrade Db compatible level to >120
- After that, do the backup the Db from this server
- Using the GCP command to import again/Perform the import from GCP Console
- That's all.

[image]